# Is possibile to configure a controller (like services) in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have my `CartDropdownController` that can be configured (i.e. setting `autoCloseDelay`) and I'm facing the following problem: **how to inject the controller** in `angular.run()` method?

```
angular.module('app')
   .controller('CartDropdownController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       this.autoCloseDelay = 3000;
       this.setAutoCloseDelay = function (autoCloseDelay ) {
           this.autoCloseDelay = autoCloseDelay;
       };

       // $scope variables here...
   }]);
```

I know that services can be injected in `.run()` (like `$http`), but my controller is not a service (and I don't know how to make it a service...).

**Edit**: why? I don't want my controller to depend on values/constants:

```
angular.module('app')
    .value('config', {
        cart: {autoCloseDelay: 1500}   
    })
    .controller('CartDropdownController', [
        '$scope',
        'config',
        function ($scope, config) {
            var autoCloseDelay = config.cart.autoCloseDelay || 3000;
            // ...
        }
   ]);
```

Comment: you cannot inject controller into run block, why do you even need it?

Comment: To inject configuration values (ie. autoCloseDelay) calling a setter. I know I can inject constants/values but I feel it's better to configure a controller like a provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docs say  [You can only inject instances (not Providers)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), and yes controller itself is also an instance, just like a service.

Now See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ysq3m/450/):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('aProvider', function() {
     console.log("factory invoked");
    return{
        fun:function(from){
   console.log("factory from"+from);
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive("test1", function() {
    console.log("directive setup");
    return {
        compile: function() {console.log("directive compile");}
    }
});

myApp.directive("test2", function() {
    return {
        link: function() {console.log("directive link");}
    }
});

myApp.run(function(aProvider) {
    console.log("app run");
  //  aProvider.fun('from run');

});

myApp.config( function() {
    console.log("app config");
});

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log("app controller");
});
```

**And the result:**

```
app config
(index):24 factory invoked
(index):46 app run
(index):33 directive setup
(index):35 directive compile
(index):56 app controller
(index):41 directive link
```

> **What happens here:**
>
> 1. config block executed
> 2. factory  is invoked(instances, services or  factories)
> 3. **run executed**
> 4. directives set
> 5. **controllers initialized**
> 6. directives linked to the page

Now here, you see run is executed first and controllers are initialized afterwords. This is why controllers cant be injected into `app.run()`

Comment: Thanks for you useful explanation. That is, the only way is to set constants/values and inject them?

Comment: @gremo: yes thats true. in your case you will need to set `autoCloseDelay`  in run and then use it in controller

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, I'm learning angular coming from PHP so it's so strange to me to "adapt" my brain :)